# C++ multi client server

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

sry but my english.

it's a simple application client-server written in C++
the operating system is OpenSUSE 13.1 Linux

I do not know how to do multi client
if you could help me I would appreciate much

All this is work with only one client

i need help, thanks

This is the
Server.cpp

```
#include "ServerSocket.cpp"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "running....\n";

  try
    {
      // Create the socket
      ServerSocket server ( 2020 );

      while ( true )
    {

      ServerSocket new_sock;
      server.accept ( new_sock );

      try
        {
          while ( true )
        {
          std::string data;
          new_sock >> data;
          std::cout << "in::" << data << std::endl;
          new_sock << data; // Respuesta
        }
        }
      catch ( SocketException& ) {}

    }
    }
  catch ( SocketException& e )
    {
      std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\nExiting.\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the
Client.cpp

```
#include "ClientSocket.cpp"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ( )
{
  try
    {

      ClientSocket client_socket ( "localhost", 2020 );

      std::string reply;

      try
    {

      std::string Envio = "";
      while(Envio != "Exit")
      {
          getline(std::cin, Envio);
          client_socket << Envio;
          client_socket >> reply;


          }



    }
      catch ( SocketException& ) {}

      std::cout << "We received this response from the server:\n\"" << reply << "\"\n";;

    }
  catch ( SocketException& e )
    {
      std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server stops accepting connections after the very first one, and enters an infinite loop (the inner `while (true)`).

How to fix this depends on how your server should serve the clients. If it accepts connection, receives request, sends reply and then forgets about the client, then you do not need the inner `while (true)`: just `<<` and `>>` operations (probably you should also close the connection), and then proceed to the next `accept`. If you need several connections to be alive, consider making your application multi-threaded (maybe spawning a new thread for each connection if number of connections is not large).